# Dynamic product filter and SEO

Tags: seo, web-crawlers

I have a "product selector/filter" that uses an external data source (JSON) for product information.  The user can adjust checkboxes or range sliders in the sidebar, and the pure front-end application dynamically creates listings of matching products.  The user can then click through to the (static) product detail page for more information.

I'm concerned about SEO, and a search engine's ability to index these product detail pages.  Since the 8000+ product links aren't actually in the HTML, my understanding is that they are effectively hidden from crawlers.  Is there a solution for this?  Will a thorough and complete XML sitemap be enough?

Comment: A sitemap is enough. I had over 800,000 pages not available through links. Google, Bing, Yandex, and Baidu all were able to find my pages just fine.

Comment: Cool.  Do you know of any info available on this from any of the major search engines?

Comment: That is what a sitemap is for! Sitemaps are designed to tell search engines about pages including pages behind a paywall or login, pages without links - ie. available through AJAX or search, and pages not otherwise linked. However, Google has recently started looking at sites with a lot of pages without links. I used Googles CSE as a solution for replacing useless and cumbersome navigation pages. The sitemap allowed Google to know about the pages they would not see otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitemap is sufficient to list all your products. However enabling category-wise navigation is advised for better results. Note that we can only list 50000  max urls in xml sitemap.